# How to return a drop-down value PyQT to another method Python

Tags: python, combobox, pyqt

I am trying to create a PyQt Dropdown menu(combo box), whose value I need to pass to another function. 
Here is a snippet of my code

```
def combo_box(self):
    combo = QtGui.QComboBox(self)
    ...#Filled in code here

    for i in range(0,len(arr)):
        combo.addItem(arr[i])

    #I want to get the value of the selected Drop-down content to be stored in value     
    value = combo.activated[str].connect(self.ComboValue)
    print value

def ComboValue(self,Text):
    print Text
    return Text
```

When I print the variable **Text** in the **ComboValue** method it prints it right, but when I print **value** from the **combo_box** method it prints None.

I wanted to know why this happens, and is there an alternative to return the value to the other method?

Answer (score 0):

combo.activated[str].connect(self.ComboValue) is signal and signal never return you anything back, so that's why you getting None. Take a look http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html

You may use this value = str(combo.currentText()), but don't know you want this.

And change combo.activated[str].connect to combo.currentIndexChanged [str].connect to get your values properly

Comment: This print out what is the initial value of the combo-box, but I need the value for every single selection I make

Answer (score 0):

create the combobox, then wait till user activates an item:

```
def combo_box(self):
    combo = QtGui.QComboBox(self)
    ...#Filled in code here

    for i in range(0,len(arr)):
        combo.addItem(arr[i])

    combo.activated.connect(self.ComboValue)
    # save it and wait for user to do something:
    self.combo = combo  

def ComboValue(self, Text):
    # user has selected an item, save it:
    self.value = Text
    assert combo.currentText() == Text
    ... do something with it ...
```

Not tested so details may be wrong.